# How to display query result in modal using the query already made outside modal tag

Tags: php, mysql, modal-dialog

I have a php file that will display the subjects (Im not gonna use dropdown anymore) of a professor along with two buttons that will display modals. The first button will display the class list of the subject via modal.

here is my code:

```
<main class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<section class="col-sm-2 scrollable" id="nav-sidebar">
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
<?php
    include("../menu/navigation.php");
?>
</ul>
</section>

<section class="col-sm-10" id="content-wrapper">

</br></br>

<div class="container-wrapper">
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("select DISTINCT CONCAT(sb.subject_code,' ',sb.subject_description,' ',c.section,' ',c.schedules,' ',c.room) as 'subject' from classes c join subjects sb on sb.subject_code = c.subjects_code join student_classes s on c.id = s.classes_id join students st on s.students_id = st.student_id where c.employees_id = '$sessionvalue2'")
        or die("No table selected " . mysql_error());

    while($cl = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo "<p style='font-size:20px'>".$cl['subject']."&nbsp &nbsp",
             '<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addLib"> See Class List </button> &nbsp &nbsp',
             '<button class="btn btn-primary"> Check Attendance </button>',
             "</p>","</br>";                                    
    }                                
?>
```

And here is my code for modal (same php file):

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addLib" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                     <div class="panel-heading">      
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h3 class="panel-title"></h3>
                     </div>
                     <br>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
<!-- Modal -->
```

Is it possible to use the same query I've used in modal? How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what jQuery code are you referring to?

Comment: The location of the query doesn't have anything to do with where it's displayed. You could use the result of the query to create a javascript variable, to generate HTML code, whatever you like.

Comment: How should I do it? I appreciate the help man.